# Just installed nodejs. Trying to create new react app. However, it's throwing me following errors

Tags: reactjs, installation, create-react-app

F:\React>npx create-react-app emall

Creating a new React app in F:\React\emall.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Nitesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-10T06_34_34_329Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting emall/ from F:\React
Done.

Not understanding why it's happening. I am not using proxy or bad network settings.

Comment: Their might be a bad connectivity of internet, you can change your network and then give it try.